# How can I adjust pictures scale according to the frequency of a song?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, scale

I'm new to CSS & JS & HTML and I was wondering how to scale an image according to the base of a song. I've looked through YouTube and many forums but can't find an answer. Anything helps :)

HTML CODE

```
<div class="animated testTransition">
    <div class="watermark">
        <img class="top" onclick="watermarkClick()" href="" src="media/webicon.png" height="70" width="70" alt="unsupported">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.watermark {
    margin-left: 1450px;
    margin-top: 665px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-webkit-transition: all 1s ease ;
    -ms-webkit-transition: all 1s ease ;
    -o-webkit-transition: all 1s ease ;
    transition: all 1s ease ;
}

.watermark:hover {
    margin-left: 1450px;
    margin-top: 665px;
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transition: all .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: pulse;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

I don't have anything JS, except for opening a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my understanding it is not possible with embedded content(like sound) because they are not played on the navigator's interpreter, but they are passed through external player library to be played. So at my knowledge you cannot do this.

However you could simulate it with random value based on the state of the embeded contrôler(isplaying, ispaused, isstopped... onplay(), onpause(), onstop()...)

Comment: Maybe you can do it with java embeded aplication that load the file. In this case you could be able to get the dataflow and visualy react to it. It is the only way I see ...